# Tkinter passing values between frames

Tags: tkinter, frames

I am working on a GUI that will collect some entry values positioned on Frame no1 and will subsequently display the values via text widget on Frame no2. Frame no1 and Frame no2 will belong to the same window.

I would like to have two classes: Input and Output. The Input class will inherit from tk.Frame class and all the variables and grid/entry methods will be set up under **init** method. I will also have some other functions that will perform calculations. I would like to use a button widget to call the Output class to display the results in the separate frame (Frame2).

The Output class will inherit from Input class and will display the results on Frame2. 
However, here is my query - if I try to inherit from the Input class, it will call again the grid methods and entry methods that I have set up under **init** methods in the Input class.
However, I would like only to use the entry values for displaying the results, not initializing the grid/entry methods.

I am a beginner so appreciate any direction etc.

Thanks
KP

Answer (score 0):

The Input class should implement the Read, Get, and Close method and if the Read method returns false (false indicates failure), that will be the end of that Input event.